# My flutter app crashes on iOS and I don't know how to point the issue

Tags: ios, flutter, crash

It says the thread 35 crashed and got this:

```
Thread 35 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-qos
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x7ff83611d00e __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff8361741ff pthread_kill + 263
2   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x7ff800132fe0 abort + 130
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff800258742 abort_message + 241
4   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff80024995d demangling_terminate_handler() + 266
5   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff800032082 _objc_terminate() + 96
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff800257b65 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 8
7   libc++abi.dylib                     0x7ff800257b16 std::terminate() + 54
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013ca4e _dispatch_client_callout + 28
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013f91a _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1278
10  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014fdf7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 414
11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800150928 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 251
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836170f8a _pthread_wqthread + 256
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff83616ff57 start_wqthread + 15
```

But I don't know how to investigate the issue, help is welcome.

The crash report is as follows (the full version doesn't fit in SO):

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Incident Identifier: 6829AC69-7A83-4B4F-BBE5-20DECC8A7B41
CrashReporter Key:   72ECC7F9-A13D-0779-EBFB-B8D97FE278A4
Hardware Model:      MacBookPro16,1
Process:             Runner [89254]
Path:                /Users/USER/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/D4B84C45-D13B-48C4-8A91-0C3B440E6CA1/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/700BCE47-B980-46D2-8DDD-0216964BE516/Runner.app/Runner
Identifier:          com.shokaze.shokaze
Version:             1.0.0 (33)
Code Type:           X86-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd_sim [68205]
Coalition:           com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimDevice.D4B84C45-D13B-48C4-8A91-0C3B440E6CA1 [12917]
Responsible Process: SimulatorTrampoline [1187]

Date/Time:           2023-04-18 00:32:09.5771 +0200
Launch Time:         2023-04-18 00:32:06.3918 +0200
OS Version:          macOS 12.6.2 (21G320)
Release Type:        User
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  35

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80042889b __exceptionPreprocess + 226
1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x7ff80004dba3 objc_exception_throw + 48
2   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff80042851d -[NSException init] + 0
3   Runner                                 0x109f8f35c GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly + 380
4   Runner                                 0x109f8f512 0x10973c000 + 8729874
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013b7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013ca3a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013f91a _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1278
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014fdf7 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 414
9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff800150928 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 251
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff836170f8a _pthread_wqthread + 256
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x7ff83616ff57 start_wqthread + 15

Thread 0::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   Runner                                 0x109f6364e 0x10973c000 + 8549966
1   Runner                                 0x109f9011c 0x10973c000 + 8732956
2   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013b7fb _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
3   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80013ca3a _dispatch_client_callout + 8
4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014c32c _dispatch_main_queue_drain + 1338
5   libdispatch.dylib                   0x7ff80014bde4 _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 31
6   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800387b1f __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
7   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff800382436 __CFRunLoopRun + 2482
8   CoreFoundation                      0x7ff8003816a7 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 560
9   GraphicsServices                    0x7ff809cb128a GSEventRunModal + 139
10  UIKitCore                              0x1283e0ad3 -[UIApplication _run] + 994
11  UIKitCore                              0x1283e59ef UIApplicationMain + 123
12  Runner                                 0x10974429f main + 63 (AppDelegate.swift:5)
13  dyld_sim                               0x10b0e22bf start_sim + 10
14  dyld                                   0x114ed552e start + 462
```

Comment: Check that you have set up all of the required identifiers for Google Ads - https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/j2mpZtnf1Ug

Comment: You're my heroes! Fill in the answer. How did you know it was related to GAD, just curious, because I was suspecting this (as the crash appeared since the GAD integration) but didn't get the real cause.

Comment: You can see that the crash was caused by `GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly` - I just googled that and found some threads that indicated it was caused by incorrectly initialised google ads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While thread 35 reported the crash, the crash was actually caused by the exception shown in "Last exception backtrace".

Looking at that backtrace, you can see that function `GADApplicationVerifyPublisherInitializedCorrectly` through an exception.  Searching Google for likely causes of that method throwing an exception indicate that you have not set up Google Ads correctly -

e.g.: https://groups.google.com/g/google-admob-ads-sdk/c/j2mpZtnf1Ug

> I was able to reproduce the crash locally, which gave me the following message:
> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'GADInvalidInitializationException', reason: 'The Google Mobile Ads SDK was initialized without an application ID. Google AdMob publishers, follow instructions at https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/admob-ios-update-plist to set a valid application ID. Google Ad Manager publishers, follow instructions at [https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist.'](https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/ad-manager-ios-update-plist.%27)
>
> Following those instructions resolved the crash.